# Pull request shows commits made by others

Tags: git, github

I am new to git. I made a commit to a branch without creating a feature branch, I raised a pull request thinking only my commit would be shown, now the pull request on github shows commits made by others.

Are the commits made by others lost if I close the pull request ?

Answer (score 1):

No, the other people's commits should be safe. You have to do some really funky stuff to delete other people's works in Git, I'd be surprised if you have. Either way, even worst case scenario, closing a pull request doesn't delete a pull request so you could if required recover it.

Git is hard at first but when it clicks it is a great tool. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

### Avoiding this

It's a good idea to always start your feature branch using your pull request's (PR) **target branch as the starting point**.

```bash
git checkout development # Or whatever branch you're going to be merging into
git pull
git checkout -b my-feature-branch
# Edit, add, commit, push, yada yada yada
```

Then when you're ready to merge, open a PR targeting the `development` branch.

### Why is GitHub showing these commits in my PR?

If you did something like in the example above, then opened a PR for `master` instead, it would show all commits that are in `development` that aren't in `master`, then your commit at the end.

That's why GitHub is showing those commits in your PR -- because they are in fact there. Your PR would introduce those commits. They're not new to the repository but they *are* new to the `master` branch.

### How to Fix it

You'd do a `git rebase -i master` and then remove all the lines that don't have your commit, then save-exit the file, and force-push. If all goes right, then congratulations, you'll have just taken a first step into a [much larger world](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing).